# C++ Implementation for Multiplying 2 polynomials using FFT

Tags: c++, implementation, fft, dft

I need to know if there is some good implementation available for the above.
I found few libraries/resources , but they seemed too complex to use , as most of them were distributed within diffrent **cpp** files.

Like , [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255474/fast-fourier-transform) , mentions quiet a few resources,but none of them fits the bill for me.

**I need a compact implementation,within just 1 cpp .**

The degree for polynomial may range **upto 10^6.** , while the coefficients are all very small,**upto 10^1.**

Comment: why don't you use FFT library then?

Comment: @BibekSubedi: i am not aware of it,please elaborate.

Comment: use library like FFTW

Comment: [KissFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) is very straightforward and easy to use.

Comment: I am not aware of this new code complexity measure 'number of cpp'.  Why does the number of cpp files matter?

Comment: Why don't you get all the cpp files and put them into one. Not sure that just having one cpp file will actually make your life easier though

Comment: I'm wondering if @Spandan means that .cpp == class?

Comment: @Yakk : It maters because i need to use fft as a sub routine,for a problem i am solving in an online judge contest.so i have to submit just one single code.